# If both deb and snap versions of the same program are installed, how do I run the mfrom the command line?

Tags: snap, deb

Using `evince` as an example, how would I run the deb and snap versions respectively from the command line if both are installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may run a specific version of your application by providing the full pathname instead of only the file name of the executable.

As such:

```
/usr/bin/evince
```

will run the deb version. The command

```
/snap/bin/evince
```

will run the snap version.

If you do not provide the full pathname, the first executable found in the PATH will be launched. By default, this will be the deb version, because the folders where these executables are installed are listed earlier in the PATH environment than `/snap/bin`, where the snap executables reside (use `echo $PATH` to view your path).